# zip4j - An error occurred while extracting files - Java

Tags: java, zip, aes, unzip, zip4j

I'm using zip4j for "wrapping my csv file into a password protected zip file". When I use Encryption as AES, its giving me an error as "**An error occurred while extracting files**". But I have my csv file inside the zip. I don't know the reason for the error. But, if I set encryption as ZIP_STANDARD, its working fine.
I'm using **zip4j - 2.11.5**.
Does this version provide support for 'AES' encryption?​ It would be really helpful if you could provide your comments on this.
Thank you.

Its working fine for ZIP_STANDARD, but not for AES, is there any way to support AES?

Comment: Your question says 'I am __compressing__ files', but your error mentions 'extracting'. Hence, your question is too unclear to answer. Is the problem that zip4j is creating zip files but whatever tool you are using to extract them is throwing that error? Is your problem that as part of the job, you are also extracting something? You didn't post any details about that. Note that zip files aren't suitable for your needs. They are a container/envelope format with the only thing 'standardized' just type-8 compression and standard encryption. 'AES' is a custom add-on.

Comment: Please take the tour and read [ask]. Right now, you've only provided a description of an error, but no details (no code or anything else comprising a [mcve]).